# tinyMCE not working in FF

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am trying to run the examples for tinyMCE editors. The examples work in IE and Chrome but do nothing in FF. I get an error in firebug saying the tinymce is not a function.
I looked on their support page, don't see anyone else having the issue. I have not altered their code or embedded it into any of my own. Just trying to run their example.
You can download it [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php). I tried the main package and jQuery package both with the same result.

Anyone have any bright ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like Firefox has restrictive access to the local file server. Once I put it on a real web server it worked.